# Obtaining the activity id from a URL for Google+?

Tags: google-plus

Suppose I have the URL for an activity (https://plus.google.com/u/0/113050383214450284645/posts/D6wBp4445Lb). I want to obtain the activity ID so that I can test the Google+ API using the APIs explorer. What is the quickest way to do this, preferably without having to write any code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to just use the API explorer to get post ids.

Grab the user ID from the url (113050383214450284645) then perform a search on it or activities.list.

Example queries for your URL:

- [Using the search API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.search?query=113050383214450284645&_h=6&)
- [Using the activities list API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list?userId=113050383214450284645&collection=public&_h=9&)

The items in the activity feed all will have the IDs that you need.

```
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "plus#activity",
   "etag": "\"vOizmBw459qRNcWY-IdfxxuCIbk/9EWWtEdBWwclTPqfqnRuN6-34Rg\"",
   "title": "Have you visited the World of Coke yet?  What was your favorite part?",
   "published": "2012-11-05T14:54:01.010Z",
   "updated": "2012-11-05T14:54:01.010Z",
   "id": "z134ctopapf0vlfec23ahjiykpj2zf0ay04",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/113050383214450284645/posts/D6wBp4445Lb",
   "actor": {
    "id": "113050383214450284645",
    "displayName": "Coca-Cola",
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/113050383214450284645",
    "image": {
     "url":         "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-3o0qMaMvuwc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAng/X3xmoXJpksI/photo.jp    g?sz=50"
    }
   },
```

In this example, the post id is z134ctopapf0vlfec23ahjiykpj2zf0ay04.

If you want to be even more accurate, you can ensure you are retrieving the right post by searching for a specific matched url.  The following code should give you a gist of how this is done in JavaScript:

```
for (var activity in activities){
  activity = activities[activity];
  if (activity['url'] == postUrl){
    targetActivity = activity;
    document.getElementById('result').value= 'ID is:\n' + activity.id;
    isFound = true;
  }
}
```

I have created a little demo that shows how this is done here:
[Demo: URL to ID](http://wheresgus.com/URLtoID)

Comment: So there's no easy way to get the ID for a specific post?

Comment: As best I know there isn't a way to translate the path for a specific post starting with the URL to the post straight into that specific post.  If you look at the response data, there is a url to the post so if you crawled through the Activity Feed until you reached the item matching the url with the one you're looking for, that would be the most effective way to accurately find the post. I have added code that you could use to this effect to the post.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up  @KhurshidAlam - fixed the demo

Comment: @class If you go to the mobile page i.e. https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream, and then click on any post it will go to to https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/ACTIVITIES-ID (for example: https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/z132zr24bq2igbqsd23gidjg4v2cft44e04). So how is this happening? May be there is a way to get Activities id from post id?