# Google+ API for reading "plus one" count

Tags: api, google-api, google-plus

Is there any *official* Google API for getting the number of "plus one" actions for a given URL?

There is [this common method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744589/89818) which doesn't seem to be using an official API.

Are we allowed to use this API at all? Even if we are, it could stop working anytime, right?

The API endpoints in the [official Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/) do all require some activity ID and thus can't give you the "plus one" count for any given URL, can they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not currently a feature of our API. You can request the feature by filing it in our Issue Tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/entry?template=Feature%20Request%20-%20REST%20API). We use these reports and the number of Stars they receive to track developer feedback.

Also, you are correct that any method call not officially supported and documented (https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/) may change in the future as we continue to build out our APIs. Sometimes clever developers find cool ways of doing things, but we do not guarantee that unsupported features will not change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So did I understand you correctly in so far as it would be okay to use this unofficial (undocumented) method call until some official method is offered or the unofficial one is shut down?

Comment: It is discouraged, but not forbidden.  Just recognize that it this is neither supported nor guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

For site analytics on your sites, you get activity on Google +1 and Share through Google analytics. You can even set up [Custom Analytics to monitor this](http://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1366830).

For the +1 widget, there is not an official API to access the counts and the APIs referenced should probably be avoided for the reasons you mention (it could stop working, may not be working correctly to begin with). I can think of a few reasons people shouldn't be able to programmatically pull analytics from any arbitrary site on the web - probably a part of the reason that this does not exist first party from Google. If you feel it's an important feature, please add or star a [feature request in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/) - you should add it to the widgets section.

For in-network activity on Google+ the [Activities resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities#resource) documents everything that is available to you when looking at content on Google+. You can, for example, +1 a post, then share the +1 and track the analytics on Google+ watching the activity if you're doing this, you should be able to use the list of "plusoners" to determine the count of people who have made +1s on a post.  See it in action using the API Explorer here:

[Activities for +GusClass](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list?userId=%252BGusClass&collection=public&_h=1&)

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I've checked that, of course, but you can't query for URLs, at least as far as I've seen. There is the list of "plusoners", but I can't search by URL.

Comment: Ahh, via URL :) You just have to combine this answer with this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878052/obtaining-the-activity-id-from-a-url-for-google/13884232#13884232 - if you are looking for the information related to a specific Google+ activity. Or, are you interested in seeing +1 activity associated with ANY url (whether or not the URL has a button or associated activity).

Comment: Yes, I actually want the "plusoners" count of _any_ URL, say a new blog article that has no Google+ button. The function that I cited in my question does that job, but it's unofficial and maybe not even allowed, I guess.