# How to get the google+ post share count, not the plus one count

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-plus, typhoeus

I am trying to find a way to get the "shares" count for a google+ post, given the url of the post.

I have searched through stackoverflow and found only the `pos.plusone.get` method that gets the plus one counts, not the shares:

```
url = "https://plus.google.com/+JohnBattelle/posts/bpxzZb3z5qt"    
mh = { method: "pos.plusones.get", id: "p", params: {nolog: true, id: url, source: "widget", userId: "@viewer", groupId: "@self"}, jsonrpc: "2.0", key: "p", apiVersion: "v1"} 
r = Typhoeus::Request.new("https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ", method: :post, body: mh.to_json, headers: {"Accept" => "application/json", "Content-type" => "application/json" } )

x = r.run
x.body
```

Returns:

```
"{\n \"id\": \"p\",\n \"result\": {\n  \"kind\": \"pos#plusones\",\n  \"id\": \"https://plus.google.com/+JohnBattelle/posts/bpxzZb3z5qt\",\n  \"isSetByViewer\": false,\n  \"metadata\": {\n   \"type\": \"URL\",\n   \"globalCounts\": {\n    \"count\": 58.0\n   }\n  },\n  \"abtk\": \"AEIZW7Sct6yKBGo7SA4ZRVvfJerD/H1RhuV/6YxCYfQC6HfEId6oDE8z43pCF4BPmRuxktNaxNSj\"\n }\n}\n"
```

I have tried sending the hash **'mh'** with different values for **method** parameter, but each returns *Not Found*. The various values I tried are:

```
pos.plus_shares.get
pos.shares.get
pos.plus_share.get
pos.public.shares.get
```

Has anyone been able to find a way to get the shares counts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to abraham I could figure out the final solution in ruby. Here it is for anyone struggling to get this data:

First, get the redirected url, to overcome the issue related to multiple google plus url formats eg. plus.google.com/u/0/+AccntName/posts/ou2342

```
def self.get_redirected_url(url)
  url_parse = URI.parse(url)
  http_response = Net::HTTP.start(url_parse.host, url_parse.port, :use_ssl => url_parse.scheme == 'https') {|http| http.request Net::HTTP::Get.new url_parse.request_uri }
  return url if http_response['location'].nil?
  http_response['location']
end
```

Next, extract the user id and post path from the url, and start using the GooglePlus gem to get the job done:

```
attributes = { plusone_count: 0 , share_count: 0, comment_count: 0 }
redirected_url = URI.parse(get_redirected_url(url))
user_id = redirected_url.request_uri.match(/\+*\w+/).to_s
post_path = redirected_url.request_uri.match(/posts\/\w+/).to_s
person = GooglePlus::Person.get(user_id)
return attributes if person.nil?
cursor = person.list_activities
cursor.each do |item|
  item_url = item.attributes['url']
  if item_url.match(post_path)
    activity_id = item.attributes['id']
    activity = GooglePlus::Activity.get(activity_id)
    attributes[:plusone_count] = activity.attributes['object']['plusoners'['totalItems']
    attributes[:share_count] = activity.attributes['object']['resharers'['totalItems']
    attributes[:comment_count] = activity.attributes['object']['replies'['totalItems']
    break
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using is a private/internal Google API. It could change without notice and break your code.

The supported method is [activities.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/get). (I'm not all that familiar with Ruby so the code might be wrong.

```
activitieId = "z13pxxpyyovky5ayk04cibwrzqbdcr3abtc0k"
apiKey = "AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ"
r = Typhoeus::Request.new("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/" + activityId + "?key=" + apiKey } )
x = r.run
activity = JSON.parse(x.body)
resharers = activity.object.resharers.totalItems
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878052/obtaining-the-activity-id-from-a-url-for-google

Comment: @user_stackoverflow If you want to add your final solution, you should do so in a new answer. Editing answers is for obvious mistakes, bugs and formatting issues, not for adding your own content or changing the meaning of the post.

Answer (score 0):

The only other way I found out so far is through Nokogiri, Tried the following in rails console:

```
url = "https://plus.google.com/+JohnBattelle/posts/bpxzZb3z5qt"
file = open(url)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(file)
puts doc.xpath("//div[@jscontroller='tH7URd']").first.children.xpath("//span[@class='MM jI']").first.children
```

Returns:

```
4
```

which is the correct shared count as of now.

But I would like to see a better way of getting this count..